# LOOPBACK: order by YEAR of a date

Tags: loopback

So, I have a model with a property of type date, let's say it's:

```
"start_date": {
  "type": "date",
  "required": true
}
```

when I get the information from this model, I would like to order by Year of that date

so instead of doing

```
{
    "order": [
        "start_date ASC"
    ]
}
```

I would like something like

```
{
    "order": [
        "dateYear(start_date) ASC"
    ]
}
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If to check **DataAccessObject._normalize()** function (**dao.js** in **loopback-datasource-juggler**), loopback do nothing special with order property of a filter and pass the result to a datasource connector.

So, looks like loopback doesn't support it. The only way to get this functionality, it should be supported by your datasource connector.